# Finding the coordinates of the third point in a triangle using simultaneous equations

Tags: triangles, systems-of-equations

I have 3 circles A,B & C that touch each other at tangents. The centre points of these 3 circles are to be joined to create a triangle. I know the coordinates of 2 of the circles centre points A(x<sub>a</sub>, y<sub>a</sub>) and B(x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>) and I know the radii of all 3 circles r<sub>a</sub>, r<sub>b</sub> & r<sub>c</sub>. I need to calculate C(x<sub>c</sub>, y<sub>c</sub>) that is the centre point of circle C using simultaneous equations. Step by step would be appreciated but just the answer is also fine.

I know this can be done easier using the Law of Cosines but I'm not allowed to use this method in this situation.